# Latency when sorting a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, sorting, datagrid

I have a WPF datagrid with 5 columns and 60 rows.
When I sort the rows clicking on the column header, there is a little latency time. If I use a winform datagrid to sort the same items,  it's much faster.

Here is my binding code and my XAML definition:

```
        public System.Data.DataTable Users{ get; set; }
    public UsersView(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        Repository = userRepository;
        InitializeComponent();
        Users = Repository.GetAll();
         usersDataGrid.DataContext = Users;
    }


<UserControl x:Class="FundTrading.UsersView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FundTrading.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">

    <DataGrid  IsReadOnly="true" SelectionMode="Single"   AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="usersDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Lavender" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Lavender" RowBackground="LightYellow" >

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id"  Binding="{Binding UserId}" Width="100" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Login Id" Binding="{Binding LoginName}" Width="100" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Description}" Width="300" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Active" Binding="{Binding Active}"  Width="100" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Role"  Binding="{Binding RoleName}" Width="300" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>


</DataGrid>
```

Is WPF really slower than Winform  or am I missing something?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I would recommend you to run your project under debug and check that Output window does not contain Binding errors when you click on column header.

Comment: It already runs in debug mode, and there is no error that appear when I click on the column headers.

Comment: Ok, then next step is to change Users type to something like List<User> (or whatever else stored in that System.Data.DataTable). If this eliminate delay then the problem is how DataGrid gather data from DataTable